# GUI layout with wxSizer, wxSashWindow

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I'm trying to create a window which is splitted into 2, 3, 4 etcc different resizable views in mainwindow and I'd like to implement that with wxWidgets in C::B. Actually th canvas itself splits the windows in the requested numbers, but it doesn't place any  sash alongn the border of views so that it's very diffciult to notice which view starts where and ends where.

I create everything on run time and I was planing to place the sash, or panels around borders of views and hoping to work in my case but the main frame is reluctant to place the panels, and sashwidnwos at the correct position and stops processing the OnSize event. That is previously working codes is not functioning properly if I add the below code with sizers and panels during resizing.

```
MainFrame *frame = new MainFrame(NULL, wxT("wxWidgets OSG Sample"),
        wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(width, height));

wxToolBar* toolbar = new wxToolBar(frame, wxID_ANY,wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTB_HORIZONTAL);

    //wxSashLayoutWindow* win = new wxSashLayoutWindow(frame, ID_WINDOW_TOP,wxPoint(50,10), wxSize(200, 30),
     //                         wxSW_3D | wxCLIP_CHILDREN);
     wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
     wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(frame, ID_TBbutton, wxPoint(300,0), wxSize(5,500));
     panel->SetWindowStyle(wxDOUBLE_BORDER);
//   panel->SetStyle(wx_3D)
     wxPanel* panel1 = new wxPanel(frame, ID_TBbutton);
     sizer->Add( panel, 0, wxALL, 0 );
     frame->SetSizer(sizer);             
     frame->SetToolBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below very basic example of MDI form with [`wxSashLayoutWindow`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_sash_layout_window.html):

```
bool SashWindowTestApp::OnInit()
{
    wxMDIParentFrame* mainFrame = new wxMDIParentFrame(NULL, ID_TEST_FRAME,
                      wxT("Sash window test"), wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(500, 400),
                      wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE);

    // top window
    wxSashLayoutWindow* topWindow = new wxSashLayoutWindow(mainFrame,
                        ID_WINDOW_TOP, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200, 100),
                        wxSW_3D);

    topWindow->SetDefaultSize(wxSize(1000, 100));
    topWindow->SetAlignment(wxLAYOUT_TOP);
    topWindow->SetBackgroundColour(*wxGREEN);
    topWindow->SetSashVisible(wxSASH_BOTTOM, true);

    // bottom window
    wxSashLayoutWindow* bottomWindow = new wxSashLayoutWindow(mainFrame,
                        ID_WINDOW_BOTTOM, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200, 200),
                        wxSW_3D);

    bottomWindow->SetDefaultSize(wxSize(1000, 200));
    bottomWindow->SetAlignment(wxLAYOUT_BOTTOM);
    bottomWindow->SetBackgroundColour(*wxYELLOW);
    bottomWindow->SetSashVisible(wxSASH_TOP, true);

    wxLayoutAlgorithm layout;
    layout.LayoutMDIFrame(mainFrame);
    mainFrame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
```

In order to have a fully working sash window your frame has to react on [`EVT_SASH_DRAGGED`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_sash_event.html)

Comment: As per the code I'm supposed to see the yellow and greeen backgrounded windows in the same MDI, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: @SonyaBlade What do you see then ? Which version of wxWidgets do you use ? What is your platform ?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2a3ygy/8 here is what I see, wxWidgets 3.0.1; Win64 ; C::B 13.12 ; MinGW 4.7.1; Having a Nvidia GeForce 610M graphic card

Comment: @SonyaBlade I tested this on Linux x64 with gtk2 library. Another idea - here is an example app from wxWidgets repository. Please check: http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/samples/sashtest