# How to create a resizable panels in wxwidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, formbuilder, wxformbuilder

I need to have 3 panles in a frame in which left panel and right panel should be reziable by the user by dragging to left or right. I have done this using AUI manager but I would like to do the same without using AUI(may be sizers). Any ideas how to achieve this?
I have tried as shown below but the i am not able to resize the panel.

MyFrame1::MyFrame1( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style ) : wxFrame( parent, id, title, pos, size, style )
{
    this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );

```
wxBoxSizer* bSizer6;
bSizer6 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

wxBoxSizer* bSizer7;
bSizer7 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

m_panel11 = new wxPanel( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
bSizer7->Add( m_panel11, 5, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5 );


bSizer7->Add( 0, 0, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );


bSizer6->Add( bSizer7, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );

wxBoxSizer* bSizer9;
bSizer9 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

m_panel12 = new wxPanel( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
bSizer9->Add( m_panel12, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5 );


bSizer6->Add( bSizer9, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );

wxBoxSizer* bSizer10;
bSizer10 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

m_panel13 = new wxPanel( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
bSizer10->Add( m_panel13, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5 );


bSizer6->Add( bSizer10, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );


this->SetSizer( bSizer6 );
this->Layout();

this->Centre( wxBOTH );
```

}

Comment: This question may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519083/gui-layout-with-wxsizer-wxsashwindow

Comment: @shawnhcorey: thanks for pointing to that link. But that is not exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want to use is a wxSplitterWindow.  You can find documentation for this class at http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_splitter_window.html.

Comment: Thanks Jon, You are right. I guess its not possible to do that with just panels. I used nested splitter window to have three partitions in the frame.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyFrame1::MyFrame1(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title,
                     const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style) :
        wxFrame(parent, id, title, pos, size, style)
{
    // use a base panel, so that you have the same background colour between controls
    // (panels in your case) too
    wxPanel* basePanel = new wxPanel(this);

    // create your controls; no need to add default values...
    m_panel11 = new wxPanel(basePanel);
    m_panel12 = new wxPanel(basePanel);
    m_panel13 = new wxPanel(basePanel);

    // create a sizer; one should be enough
    wxSizer* bSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    // add your controls to the sizer
    bSizer->Add(m_panel11, 1, wxEXPAND|wxALL, 5);
    bSizer->Add(m_panel12, 0, wxEXPAND|wxUP|wxDOWN|wxRIGHT, 5);
    bSizer->Add(m_panel13, 1, wxEXPAND|wxUP|wxDOWN|wxRIGHT, 5);
    // if you need different resizing proportion for each panel, read the description
    // of proportion parameter in wxSizer:Add() docs

    basePanel->SetSizer(bSizer);
}
```

Comment: Hey catalin thanks for your reply, I executed your code in visual studio. I do not see any resizeable panels visible.